# R Selection by value, avoid NA

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

I try extract rows by values.

```
col1 <- c("A", "B", "C", NA)
df <- data.frame(col1)
df$col1[col1 == "A"]
```

The result in console is

```
> df$col1[col1 == "A"]
[1] "A" NA
```

But of course I only want "A". How to avoid R selecting NA values? By the way I think this behavior is pretty dangerous as many would run into this trap e.g. replacing values, subsetting, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use `%in%` which returns `FALSE` for `NA` values.

```
df$col1[col1 %in% "A"]
#[1] "A"
```

Answer (score 4):

`filter` from `dplyr` automatically drops the `NA` elements even if the relational operator is `==`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(col1 == 'A') %>% 
   pull(col1)
#[1] "A"
```

---

Or using the `sbt` (for subsetting) from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
sbt(df, col1 == 'A')$col1
#[1] "A"
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that for the `collapse` code presented, using `%>%` would have given error: `df %>% sbt(col1 == "A")$col1` which ends with the error: `Error in .$sbt(col1 == "A") : 3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2`

Answer (score 3):

As Markus mentioned in the comments, a base solution is:

```
df$col1[which(df$col1 == "A")]
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
str_subset(df$col1, "A")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `is.element`:

```
df[is.element(col1,"A"),]
#[1] "A"
```

Or simply filter out `NA`:

```
df[col1 == "A" & !is.na(col1),]
#[1] "A"
```